# Session PHP Security

Tags: php

I have the following php code for php sessions, and wondering if it's really secure.

```
// Session Security
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', '1');
ini_set('session.session.use_only_cookies', '1');
ini_set('session.entropy_file', '/dev/urandom');
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', '0');
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', '1');

session_name("nameofsite");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');

if (!isset($_SESSION))
    session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header("Location: /home.php");

    die();
}
```

When the "user" logs in - I regenerate a new session id by doing this:

```
if ($worked['loginname'] == sha1($username) && $worked['password'] == sha1($password))
{
    echo Message("Please wait, you are being logged in.");
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=index.php'>";

    $_SESSION['id'] = $worked['id'];
    $_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    session_regenerate_id(true);
}
```

Should I also check if the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] matches $_SESSION['ip']?

I just want to have a secure site, so sessions can't be hijacked/stolen.

Comment: Do you even have a SSL Certificate?

Comment: As much as you want it to be secure all of this is pointless without TLS (SSL). The only thing to think about with regards to IP is that it can legitimately change during a session. Phone drops from WiFi to 3G etc...

Comment: @DarylGill - not yet, but im considering it, security above anything.

Comment: Just noticed actually that you're setting the `secure` flag on the cookie so you must be running with an SSL cert?

Comment: @ScottHelme - I copied and pasted this, a friend who is coder as well gave me this and said it would secure sessions, but if that's only for SSL then I probably will remove the line.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-secure if you don't have SSL the browser will never transmit the cookie if you flag it as `secure`.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't check the IP address because a user's IP can change for many genuine reasons. For example a phone dropping from WiFi to 3G, they're behind a load balancer or using something like the Tor network.

Comment: Would you suggest something different I should check? I want to have the session secure against hijacking ect, preferably without SSL, but if SSL secures it 100% then I probably will buy a certificate and implement it.

Comment: Session hijacking occurs when an attacker gains access to the session cookie. There is nothing you can do in code to prevent the cookie from being sent in clear text. Once it's sent in the clear an attacker can sniff it from the transport layer and inject it into their own session. The only thing you can do is use Transport Layer Security (TLS/SSL). Search my blog for "session hijacking" for more info: https://scotthelme.co.uk

Answer (score 2):

### Secure Session Handling

```
ini_set('session.entropy_file', '/dev/urandom');
```

This is good. Make sure `session.entropy_length` is a reasonable value: at least 16 (128 bits), less than or equal to 64 (512 bits).

> Should I also check if the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` matches `$_SESSION['ip']`?

You *can* bind a session to a particular IP address, but as Scott Helme says, this will break for Tor / 3G / open WiFi users. I don't recommend it.

> When the "user" logs in - I regenerate a new session id...

Yes. Escalating privileges should result in a session ID regeneration. You're doing that right.

#### Other Considerations

- HTTPS is mandatory for session security; this is not negotiable.
- [Hypertext-Strict-Transport-Security](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) is highly recommended.
- Only use cookies for session ID storage.
- Don't store the cookie state in a cookie; this design flaw has led to many security vulnerabilities in popular frameworks and CMSes that I have personally found. (Including, yes, CodeIgniter and Laravel.) It has become one of the first things I look for when auditing a PHP project.

Refer to our article [PHP session security](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/fast-track-safe-and-secure-php-sessions) for more in-depth explanations and ideas you might want to consider (e.g. canary values to mitigate the risk of session fixation, which shouldn't be a concern if you only use cookies over HTTPS). You should also make sure you aren't vulnerable to [cross-site scripting vulnerabilities](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/06/preventing-xss-vulnerabilities-in-php-everything-you-need-know).

---

#### User Authentication

```
if ($worked['loginname'] == sha1($username) && $worked['password'] == sha1($password))
```

This is the least secure part of your question.

1. Why are you `sha1()` hashing the username? That seems pointless.
2. Why are you `sha1()` hashing the password? [That is definitely insecure](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2015/05/phps-magic-hash-vulnerability-or-beware-of-type-juggling).

You should use an [appropriate PHP cryptography tool for storing passwords](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded). In PHP 5.5 and newer, we have [`password_hash()` and `password_verify()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php). For earlier versions of PHP (5.3.7 minimum), you can use [ircmaxell/password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

[Secure user authentication](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence) is challenging, especially when it long-term authentication (i.e. a cookie set by a "remember me on this computer" checkbox) comes into the equation.